# Getting "No such file or directory" error when trying run a sql app using sqlite3 driver

Tags: gcc, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    DB, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "/Users/MyUser/Documents/GO Proj/test.db")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
    }
    defer DB.Close()
}
```

Everytime I run this code (Using `Sublime Text` 3, Mac OS X 10.9) I get this:

```
exec gcc: No such file or directory
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6l: running gcc failed: unsuccessful exit status 0x100
[Finished in 1.4s with exit code 2]
```

Comment: Eh... it says you don't have gcc. Do you?

Comment: You may need to grab XCode and do the 'Install Command Line Tools' dance.

Comment: well if I run gcc from terminal I get: clang error: No input files, so I guess I have it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by changing the path go.sublime-build file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/go/bin/go", "run", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(.*?)\\(([0-9]+)\\)",
    "selector": "source.go",
    // "path": "/usr/local/go/bin"
}
```

Comment out `"path"` and added `"/usr/local/go/bin/go"` in `"cmd"`.